# how to make my video play when hover on it with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i try to do this with many different way but i didn't get the result i want so can anyone help

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <video controls autoplay width="400" height="400">
        <source src="video/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</div>
```

and here is the only answer i found when i search but i dont understand it well and there is jquery on it i want to make it pure javascript

```
var figure = $(".video");
var vid = figure.find("video");

[].forEach.call(figure, function (item,index) {
item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo.bind(item,index), false);
item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo.bind(item,index), false);
});

function hoverVideo(index, e) {
vid[index].play(); 
}

function hideVideo(index, e) {
vid[index].pause(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer is pretty simple:

```js
document.getElementById("myVid").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
 this.play();
});

document.getElementById("myVid").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
 this.pause();
});
```

```html
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <video id="myVid" controls autoplay width="400" height="400">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</div>
```

Comment: i wrote the code like this but it didn't work when i copy past you code and use it it work just fine so what may be the reason

Comment: Can I see your code, or is it the same code you have in your question?

Comment: js:19 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.
You can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) about HTML5 video API.

```js
const videoPlayer = document.querySelector('.videoplayer');

videoPlayer.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    videoPlayer.play();
});
```

```html
<p>Hover canvas to play the video</p>
<video class="videoplayer" width="320" height="240">
  <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: thanks alot man i wrote my code like this but i think there was a problem because it didn't work

Comment: Which browser do you use? Could you please share your previous code?

Comment: i use google chrome i think may be because my video is long and need time to load i use video on my computer
      <div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
 <video id="play" controlwidth="400" height="400">
  <source src="video/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video> 
 </div>

 and here is my js

    var videoAct = document.getElementById('play');

videoAct.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 this.play();
});
videoAct.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
 this.pause();
});

Comment: i want to know how to use this for more than one video on my html on the same div tag

Comment: I've created a simple example for more than 1 video within a div tag. [demo](http://jsbin.com/bukewozaho/edit?html,js,output). P.S. Don't forget to focus 'Output' area, before hovering videos.

Comment: okay 
i try to make my video mute when i hover on it and use this code 
    var videoAct = document.getElementById('myplay');

videoAct.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 this.play();
 this.removeAttribute('muted');
});
videoAct.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
 this.pause();
 this.setAttribute('muted');
});

Comment: Which one? If you are talking about the previous example with 'general div'. You can find a link in the previous comment. (P.S. the word 'demo' is clickable)

Comment: okay and what about to make my video muted when i hover on it

Comment: Add `muted` attribute directly in the HTML like this `<video id="play" width="200" height="200" muted>...</video>`. Or use `event.target.muted = true;` in JavaScript.

Comment: can you explain to me what you wrote in your if condition i didn't understand it

Comment: i use this code to make many video play and i try to add muted Attr by it but i didn't
work don't know why can you figure out a solution

    var videoAct = document.querySelectorAll('video');

videoAct.forEach(function(video){
 video.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 this.play();
 this.removeAttribute('muted');
});
video.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
 this.pause();
 this.setAttribute('muted');
});
})

Comment: Yes, sure. I check if the current element under my pointer of the mouse (within `div` element) is `video` tag. If this is a `video` tag then we can call `.play()` method of the element. In case this is not `video` tag -- ignore.

Comment: Change `this.setAttribute('mute');` to `video.mute = true`; It should helps :)

Comment: roman i have a poster in my video this poster removed when i hover so i want it to back when i am not hovering i try to use this 
    videoAct.forEach(function(video){
 video.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 this.play();
 video.muted = true;
 if(video.hasAttribute('poster')){
  if(video.poster === 'video/8.jpg'){
   video.setAttribute('poster', '');
  }
 }
});
video.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
 this.pause();
 if(video.hasAttribute('poster')){
  if(video.poster === ''){
   video.setAttribute('poster', 'video/8.jpg');
  }
 } 
});

Comment: I think this behavior is incorrect and shouldn't be handled in such a way. The only one solution comes to my mind is to create the custom overlay with your poster and adds/removes the 'overlay div' when it needed instead of setting via the attribute.

P.S. Use simple styles to your code when you use it in comments.

Comment: i thought about that too and i did it

Comment: js:19 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException